# Extract the mongodb json array element into json python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have mongodb document as an array and need to create json file in python.

**mongodb document looks like**

```
db.mappedfields.insertMany(
[ 
    {   sourceAttribute: "first_name",
        domainAttribute: "First_Name"},
    {   sourceAttribute: "last_name",
        domainAttribute: "Last_Name"}
]
```

**Code tried**

```
class create_dict(dict):    
  def __init__(self):
    self = dict()

  def add(self, key, value):
    self[key] = value

mydict = create_dict()
i = 1
for key in mycol.find():
    mydict.add(i, ({key['sourceAttribute']:key['domainAttribute']}))
    i = i+1

json_data = json.dumps(mydict, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

**Output getting**

```
{
  "1": {
    "first_name": "First_Name"
  },
  "2": {
    "last_name": "Last_Name"
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "first_name": "First_Name",
    "last_name": "Last_Name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pymongo

class create_dict(dict):

  # __init__ function
  def __init__(self):
    self = dict()

    # Function to add key:value

  def add(self, key, value):
    self[key] = value

mydict = create_dict()

i = 1
for key in mycol.find():
    mydict.add(i, ({key['input']:key['output']}))
    i = i+1

json_data = json.dumps(mydict, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
json_data1 = json.loads(json_data)
dictlist = []

for key, value in json_data1.items():
    dictlist.append(value)
print(dictlist)

result = {}
for d in dictlist:
    result.update(d)


print(result)
```